# Master password authentication?

Tags: authentication, passwords, odoo, admin, odoo-8

I am trying to create a user by retrieving `username, password and database_name` from a web page using a route `/web/my_route`. It successfully create the user. But i need to add a field `master_password` in web page and authenticate it to create user. I tried to find out master_password authentication functionality, but nothing find except below code

```
@http.route('/web/database/create', type='json', auth="none")
def create(self, fields):
    params = dict(map(operator.itemgetter('name', 'value'), fields))
    db_created = request.session.proxy("db").create_database(
        params['super_admin_pwd'],
        params['db_name'],
        bool(params.get('demo_data')),
        params['db_lang'],
        params['create_admin_pwd'])
    if db_created:
        request.session.authenticate(params['db_name'], 'admin', params['create_admin_pwd'])
    return db_created
```

But i couldn't find the function `create_database`. 
How can i do it? any suggestion ??

Comment: The code you found involves creating an entirely new odoo database and that is probably not what you want. What do you mean you need to add a field master_password? Why?

Comment: I have multiple databases, so i need a super_admin for all database, that's what i am trying to create. Now all working fine, but anybody can create this user with out any authentication, if i can authenticate using master_password it's great.

Comment: So do I understand correctly you have a page which creates a user in the res_users table in a database (picked from a list), and you want to protect that page? And you want to create a master_password for it that you store somewhere?

Comment: i don't need to create a master_password, we already have one which used to create/drop databases. I need to use that password and authenticate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the field on the form, and on submit check it against `odoo.tools.config['admin_passwd']`. This is the master admin password.